# How to get bounced emails in CakePHP?

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I am sending email using cakePHP 2.0. everything is working fine but how to catch bounced emails? i already added replyTo and return but still not getting bounced emails.

```
$this->Email->sendAs = 'both';
$this->Email->from = 'abc@xyz.com';
$this->Email->to = 'wrong@wrong.com';
$this->Email->replyTo = 'abc@xyz.com';
$this->Email->return = 'abc@xyz.com';
$this->Email->headers = ['Return-Path'=>'abc@xyz.com'];
$this->Email->subject = 'Test Eail';
$msg = 'Message';
$this->Email->send($msg);
```

Comment: This is out of scope for CakeEmail. Basically you need to implement something that listens on your Inbox for bounce Mails. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097382/how-to-handle-mail-delivery-errors-with-php

Comment: @polyte  but at Email account i am not getting bounce mails

Comment: I am just sending email by code and checking email at email client (outlook etc)

Comment: Are you using the SMTP transport?

Comment: @GregSchmidt No, using php mail ()

Comment: That's probably your problem. The standard `mail` function does none of this. At best it will just return false if the mail fails, but I think there are situations where it can't even detect that.